# How can i optimize my PrimeDivisor Function

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I have function which find values of prime divisors.    (http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/prime-factors.php)

For example it takes 12 and produce 2*2*3  = 2,3 if it would take 10 it will produce 2*5 = 2,5 like that

My Code at below:

```
 public List<Integer> findPrimeDivisor(int value) {

        ArrayList<Integer> divisors = new ArrayList<>();

        int startPoint = 2;

        if (isRound(value, startPoint)) {
            divisors.add(startPoint);
        }

        while (value != 1) {
            if (isRound(value, startPoint)) {
                value /= startPoint;
                continue;
            }
            startPoint++;
            divisors.add(startPoint);
        }

        return divisors;
    }

    private boolean isRound(int value, int roundBy) {
        return (value % roundBy) == 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

**How can i do it more effectively ? Thanks for yours suggestions :)**

Comment: Google "java factorization" for lots of pointers (including many on this site).

Comment: If this enumerated all prime divisors of all numbers of its domain (15?), there would be no way to do this more effectively: once you get the effect wanted, no other algorithm nor implementation would be more effective. Efficiency - effort per result - is another matter altogether; just don't forget to include user and programmer effort appropriately. The biggest roles in efficiently enumerating prime divisors of a natural number would seem math to me, followed by algorithm, then coding - there is a Stack Exchange sites for each.

Answer (score 1):

Your prime number divisor calculator is not working for several reasons so it wouldn't be very logical to try improving it directly. Here are some of the reasons :

- Does not calculate whether a candidate is prime or not ( this is
  crucial )
- Starts from number 2 and adds to the result set if it DOES NOT divide
  the value ( you should try for the opposite )
- Once it finally finds a number that can divide the value, it DOES NOT
  add the divident to the result set (again you should go for the
  opposite here )

If you are looking for a way to just find them, you can use one of the many libraries that are available but if you want to start making your own, I suggest for you to start small and divide your problem into pieces:

- A method to find primes ( which should cache its results )
- A method to try all logically possible candidates
- A method to find all logically possible candidates

An example might be :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(findPrimeDivisors(25));
    System.out.println(findPrimeDivisors(12));
    System.out.println(findPrimeDivisors(10));
    System.out.println(findPrimeDivisors(50));
}

// Should be cached or maybe even hardcoded to a point
public static boolean isPrime(int number)
{
    for(int i = 2; i <= number/2; i++)
        if(number % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

// Main loopbreaker, decides whether the next candidate should be tried or not, can be more efficient
public static boolean tryNext(int candidate, int value)
{
    return value / candidate >=  2;
}

public static List<Integer> findPrimeDivisors(int value)
{
    List<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int candidate = 2;
    while(tryNext(candidate,value))
    {
        if(isPrime(candidate) && (value % candidate == 0)) resultList.add(candidate);
        candidate++;
    }

    return resultList;
}
```